# In practice, will a C# struct with a single member be as efficient as using that single member outside of a struct?

Tags: c#, optimization, struct

I am developing a library which internally passes around integer values which are not really integers but convenient containers of bits.

For my own sanity, I'd prefer to instead do this...

```
internal struct MyStruct
{
    private readonly int myInt;
    /* Constructor and get accessors. */
}
```

... and pass around MyStruct values instead of int values. This way I can use my nice get accessors and the compiler will prevent me from using the wrong type.

Can I be reasonably sure that I've not introduced an inefficiency by doing this? It feels like once the compiler has done its thing, all uses of MyStruct should boil down to a simple int, taking up a single register just as an int would.

My experience tells me that single member structs do indeed compile down the way I would want them to, but I'm having trouble pinning that down to anything more than a gut feeling.

Comment: Not really sure why you need a struct here, why not just pass around the int instead?

Comment: @DavidG Type safety and convenient get accessors. myvalue.Flarn vs GetFlarn(myvalue)

Comment: Well, by looking at the compiled version of this (in release build) i can tell you that the Stuct won't be compiled away... that still remains a struct with an int field in it.

Comment: @gregkalapos Are you looking at the CIL/MSIL or the machine code?

Comment: You could also add the `get` methods using extension methods.

Comment: CIL/MSIL... machine code would depend on the JIT

Comment: Though honestly, if you're concerned about performance, then you need to test, test and test. Micro-optimisations are frequently a waste of time unless they're called millions of times.

Comment: @DavidG Then every integer would have a .Flarn accessor, Even when its nonsensical.

Comment: So what if it does?

Comment: @DavidG - There are other types with just an int underneath, so I'd need .FlarnForAFlorn and .FlarnForAFlurn as well, being careful not to accidentally use myFlorn.FlarnForAFlurn which is, of course, nonsensical. :)

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your code, but it does seem to indicate a code smell if you really need all those distinct methods. Perhaps it's time for some refactoring?

Comment: @DavidG - I want to avoid having so many distinct methods by sorting them into a separate structs, hence my original question.

Comment: @DavidG - This is a library that would indeed be called "millions of times" in a tight loop.

Comment: @gregkalapos - I'm chiefly concerned with what the machine code would look like, as this question is about run-time optimization. The MSIL is just a one more phase on the route to being run on the silicon.

Comment: @billpg Sure, it's "one more phase on the route to being run on the silicon", but that is what you can control in a managed environment. If you want to optimise for the machine code, then in case of a library you have to make sure it's "optimal" for RyuJIT, the classic JIT, to the mono JIT and to any other JIT which will be released in the future - on every platform and bitness (hint: CoreCLR-cross platform). What I want to point out: this is maybe not the most efficient approach to make your lib better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only half an answer: I believe you are correct in that the struct member is simply part of the struct itself and therefore gets passed around the same way as an int would, as the struct and the int have the same size (though I can't find a definitive answer from the language spec).

However, there is a surprising performance penalty to be paid for making your member readonly. See John Skeet's explanation at https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/07/16/micro-optimization-the-surprising-inefficiency-of-readonly-fields/

I would therefore make your member non-readonly, and just not create any mutators for it.

Comment: Neither the C# spec nor the CIL spec mandate that a `struct` with a single `int` member has a specific size. The size of a value type is implementation-dependent and padding is allowed. This is deliberate, to increase portability. (In practical terms, they would be the same size, and they certainly are on the .NET Framework.) You can override this by explicitly indicating the layout (`StructLayoutAttribute`), though that's of course of little interest in a single-member struct.